# cannot find -lclient.d Makefile error

Tags: c++, makefile

I am getting error cannot find -lab_client.d. I have checked this lib exists in the lib path i am giving. -

```
g++ -fPIC -D GCC_BUILD -D _debug -D _LIB -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB -std=c++0x tmp.buildfiles/gcc_`gcc --version| cut -d " " -f 3|head -1`_`uname -p`/ab_client_test.d.o  -L"../ab_client/boost/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib_gcc_4.1.2_x64/" 
-L"../lib/gcc_`gcc --version| cut -d " " -f 3|head -1`_`uname -p`" **-L"/users/bhrdw/enlistments/ab_client/trunk/ab_client/lib/gcc_4.4.7_x86_64"** -static -Wl,--start-group -lab_Client.d -lboost_exception -lboost_atomic 
-lboost_chrono -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread  -lboost_exception -lpthread -lrt -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-rpath,./ -o ../bin/gcc_`gcc --version| cut -d " " -f 3|head -1`_`uname -p`/ab_client_test.d
```

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lab_client.d

I see path : -L"/users/bhrdw/enlistments/ab_client/trunk/ab_client/lib/gcc_4.4.7_x86_64" is included and i checked the file libab_client.d.so exists at this location.

Please help me out. I am stuck on this.

Comment: `libab_client_test.d.so` isn't `libab_client.d.so`. Isn't it the case?

Comment: sorry. corrected typo. Its libab_client.d.so.

Comment: `usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lab_client.d`. Well, the string `ab_client.d`
does not occur in the commandline you have posted.